# Не получается переопределить __setattr__

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем доброго времени суток!
Сижу, разбираюсь с ООП. Вот написал маленький кусочек кода и пытаюсь разобраться:

```
class Point:
    Peppa = 6

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key == 'Peppa':
            raise NameError('SwinkaError')
        else:
            self.__dict__[key] = value
```

Объясните мне, пожалуйста:
Почему, если я пишу дальше вот так:

```
pt = Point(4,10)
pt.Peppa = 15
```

то ошибка бросается. `NameError: SwinkaError`
А если я пишу во так:

```
pt = Point
pt.Peppa = 15
```

То интерпретатор не бросает ошибку и присваивает свойству 15.
Что вообще означает, когда создаётся экземпляр от класса без скобок? (т.е. когда пишется `pt = Point`, а не `pt = Point()`)

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: https://ideone.com/8oxaVD

Comment: "_создаётся экземпляр от класса без скобок_", — экземпляр **не создаётся**, а `Point.Peppa = 15` присваивает значение атрибуту **класса**. Всё в `Python` — объект, класс в том числе.

Comment: pt = Point - ссылка на класс. Следующим оператором вы создаете переменную класса

Comment: @nomnoms12, а почему такое не работает? https://ideone.com/J2cY6N & https://ideone.com/DnhwCF.

Comment: @splash58 А вы не могли бы, пожалуйста, объяснить, разницу между экземпляром класса и ссылкой на класс? Или тыкнуть меня носом в какую-нибудь статью, где бы это доступно объяснялось. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: вот первое же, что поиск дал - https://programmera.ru/uroki-po-python/staticheskie-peremennye-klassa-v-python/

Comment: @splash58 спасибо! А что значит фраза:  " Статические переменные существуют только в одном экземпляре для каждого класса и не создаются." Как понять только в одном экземпляре? А если экземпляров несколько, то как узнать какому из экземпляров принадлежит данная статическая переменная?  И я, честно говоря, так и не понял, что я сделал объявив `pt = Point`  :(

Comment: @Qwertiy Потому что переопределять магические методы таким образом нельзя. Интерпретатор ищет их иначе, через тип экземпляра, и в словаре объекта их нет. Но даже если добавить их в словарь объекта, они будут иметь меньший приоритет. В Вашем случае `Point` — экземпляр класса `type`, поэтому `Python` использует `__setattr__`, реализованный в `C`.

Comment: @Qwertiy С обычными методами такое переопределение сработает.